# How to assign Enum with description to DataGridViewComboBoxCell

Tags: c#

This is my enum

```
public enum FilterOperatorEnum
        {
            [Description("=")]
            OPER_EQUAL = 0,
            [Description("!=")]
            OPER_NOT_EQUAL = 1,
            [Description(">")]
            OPER_MORE_THAN = 2,
            [Description("<")]
            OPER_LESS_THAN = 3,
            [Description("InRange")]
            OPER_IN_RANGE = 4,
            [Description("OutRange")]
            OPER_OUT_RANGE = 5
        }
```

How to assign this enum to DataGridViewComboBoxCell's DataSource, valueMemeber and DisplayMemeber.

And how to get enum value(0,1,2...) from selected index of the DataGridViewComboBoxCell.
I tried with the solution given in the link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39163/loading-a-combobox-with-an-enum-and-binding-to-it but it is not working for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Eval` to assign DataSource and `Enum.Parse` to convert posted data to `FilterOperatorEnum`. This is a simple example that works:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList DataSource='<%# Eval("DropDownDataSource") %>' DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Value" ID="myDropDown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Behind code:

```
public enum FilterOperatorEnum
{
    [Description("=")]
    OPER_EQUAL = 0,
    [Description("!=")]
    OPER_NOT_EQUAL = 1,
    [Description(">")]
    OPER_MORE_THAN = 2,
    [Description("<")]
    OPER_LESS_THAN = 7,
    [Description("InRange")]
    OPER_IN_RANGE = 4,
    [Description("OutRange")]
    OPER_OUT_RANGE = 5
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<object> DropDownDataSource { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        fillGrid();
}

private void fillGrid()
{
    var itemNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(FilterOperatorEnum));
    var dsDropDown = new List<object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemNames.Length; i++)
        dsDropDown.Add(new { Name = GetEnumDescription((FilterOperatorEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(FilterOperatorEnum), itemNames[i])), Value = itemNames[i] });

    var dataSource = new List<MyModel>
    {
        new MyModel() { Id = 1, DropDownDataSource = new List<object>(dsDropDown) },
        new MyModel() { Id = 2, DropDownDataSource = new List<object>(dsDropDown) }
    };

    GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    return attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0
        ? attributes[0].Description 
        : value.ToString();
}
```

Html rendered in the first dropDown:

```
<select name="ctl00$MainContent$GridView1$ctl02$myDropDown" id="MainContent_GridView1_myDropDown_0">
    <option value="OPER_EQUAL">=</option>
    <option value="OPER_NOT_EQUAL">!=</option>
    <option value="OPER_MORE_THAN">&gt;</option>
    <option value="OPER_IN_RANGE">InRange</option>
    <option value="OPER_OUT_RANGE">OutRange</option>
    <option value="OPER_LESS_THAN">&lt;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @userrmgs is the same idea: `comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value"; comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name"; comboBox1.DataSource = dsDropDown;` 
On SelectedIndexChanged `FilterOperatorEnum selectedItem = (FilterOperatorEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(FilterOperatorEnum), (string)comboBox1.SelectedValue);`

Comment: thank you it is working. Initially how  to set particular index in Combobox.

Comment: @userrmgs ;) use `comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 /*0, 1, 2, etc. */;`